Computing Cauchy-Principal value with residue theorem on the positive line?
I'm trying to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{PV}\int_0^{+\infty}dy\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2a^2}{(y-b)}}
\end{equation}
with $a$ and $b$ positive.
I have tried to compute an antiderivative by change of variables $y^2a^2 = \cosh(x)$ but I couldn't work anything out. I thought of using a residue theorem along the real line but I don't think it'll work.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you!

Can you write down what is the limit formula you are using for the principle value integration?

the integral diverges at $y\to\infty$

Echoing @Svyatoslav's comment: at $+\infty$, the integrand looks like $1/y$, and there's no oscillation, so it diverges at infinity, in addition to the (reparable, by principal value...) issue at $y=b$. Is there a typo?

I use \begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\left[\int_{0}^{-\epsilon + b} + \int_{\epsilon+b}^{+\infty}\right]dy\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2a^2}(y-b)}
\end{equation}

@MohamedSU - yes, that is how to take the CPV at $y = b$. But it doesn't help with the divergence at $\infty$. Not matter what $\epsilon > 0$ is, $\int_{\epsilon + b}^\infty$ will be infinite.

$$\frac{y}{(y-b)\sqrt{1+a^2 y^2} }=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 y^2}}+\frac{b}{(y-b)\sqrt{1+a^2 y^2} }$$
$$I=\int \frac{b}{(y-b)\sqrt{1+a^2 y^2} }\,dy$$
$$y=\frac{\sinh (t)}{a} \quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{b}{\sinh (t)-a b}\,dt$$
Half-angle substitution
$$I=-\frac{2 b \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a b \tanh \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}$$
Back to $y$
$$\int\frac{y}{(y-b)\sqrt{1+a^2 y^2} }\,dy=\frac{\sinh ^{-1}(a y)}{a}-\frac{2 b \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2 y^2+1}+a (b-y)}{\sqrt{a^2
   b^2+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}$$
If $y\to \infty$
$$I=\frac{\log (y)}{a}+\Bigg(\frac{\log \left(4 a^2\right)}{2 a}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}\log \left(\frac{1-\frac{a b}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}}{\frac{a b}{1+\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1}}}\right)\Bigg)+O\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$
